# Is there an analog of numpy.save for lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Is there a function like numpy.save but such that it saves a list (not an array) to a binary file?

Let's say I want to save a heterogeneous list that contains numbers and characters

```
a = [1,2,3,4,'a']
```

If I save it with numpy.save, and then load it

```
np.save('a.npy',a)
b = np.load('a.npy').tolist()
```

then I get a list of characters only:

```
print(type(b),b)

<class 'list'> ['1', '2', '3', '4', 'a']
```

Comment: `np.save` first turns `a` into an array, and then saves it.  Look at `np.array(a)`.  Python `pickle` can save a list.  `pickle` of an array uses the `save` format, and `save` uses `pickle` to format any `object` dtype elements.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks! Looks like pickle works. I did it like this: `import pickle

a = [1, 1.2, 'a']

fileObject = open('a.list','wb') 
pickle.dump(a,fileObject)   
fileObject.close()

fileObject = open('a.list','rb')  
b = pickle.load(fileObject)  

print(b)`

Answer (score 0):

This would certainly work

```
lst = [1, 1.2, 'a']

with open("lst.list", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(lst))

with open("lst.list", "r") as infile:
    loaded = eval(infile.read())

print(loaded)  # [1, 1.2, 'a']
```

Comment: It saves it to a text file, not to binary file. Is these something that uses less space?